# List & Label 19 - Web reporting sample app requires designer plugin

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, listlabel

I have access to Combit's List&Label 19 installation. In the install dir, there are some sample apps. I am interested in Web-reporting ASP .NET c# app. I open the solution file and hit run in IE. Subsequently the sample app is started in IE (in my case IE 11). When I click on "Design report", it keeps saying that I need to install designer plugin. On Combit website I have found such plugins for opera, chrome, firefox, safari, but nothing for IE. In my opinion IE should be supported by default, but It is not working. Can anybody please help me?
Thx

Comment: Can anyone tell me the reason of downrating my question? I thing it is related to app development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE 11 was released with Windows 8.1 first and combit's List&Label 19 was released at the nearly same time. This problem is fixed in List&Label 19.001